# When searching how to make UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark the correct cell?

Tags: arrays, uisearchbar, checkmark, uitableview

I have a view controller with 2 arrays, one for normal results; the other for filtered/search results based off text entry.

Only one cell can have the UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark at a time.

My problem can be described thusly;

IE:

1. View controller is fed a Venue object; and is marked with
   UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark.  This is expected, and correct.
2. User types in a search query, the search results array is used;
   however the UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark is no longer on the
   Venue that was previously checked in step 1.

I am not sure why its not checking the cell.

Visual examples;

Original view. `Cobo Arena` is the pre-selected venue

[image: First view]

-

When typing;  The checkmark is not in the right place

[image: Searching filters the results]

-

More typing:  The checkmark is now gone

[image: More typing]

-

The code is below

```
- (void) configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FCVenue *venue;

    if (self.isSearching)
    {
        venue = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        venue = [self.venues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    if ([indexPath isEqual:self.selectedIndexPath])
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", venue.name];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", venue.location];
}

-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.selectedIndexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    self.selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.selectedIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    return indexPath;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    FCVenue *venue;

    if (self.searching)
    {
        venue = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        venue = [self.venues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    self.selectedVenue = venue;

// This method fires a completion block and dismisses the view controller
    if (self.completionBlock)
    {
        self.completionBlock( self, self.selectedVenue );
    }

    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's happening because you are storing the index of the full table to display the checkmark. Instead you should compare the FCVenue object to see if that is the one checked or not.

So the code should be something like this, it is not tested though:

```
- (void) configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FCVenue *venue;

    if (self.isSearching)
    {
        venue = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        venue = [self.venues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    if ([venue isEqual:self.selectedVenue]) // You may want to compare just the id or any other unique property
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        // if you opt for keeping the selectedIndexPath property you need to refresh it here.
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", venue.name];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", venue.location];
}

-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   //[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.selectedIndexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    // Here you may want to do a loop over all the possible index path to clean the state or keep storing the selected indexPath just to clear the mark when the selected venue changes.
    FCVenue *venue;

    if (self.searching)
    {
        venue = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        venue = [self.venues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    self.selectedVenue = venue;
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    return indexPath;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];



// This method fires a completion block and dismisses the view controller
    if (self.completionBlock)
    {
        self.completionBlock( self, self.selectedVenue );
    }

    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    }];
}
```

In any case the general idea is that you need to tie the venue with the check and not with at indexPath as the indexPath will change with the search.